# Can i get more battery life than this?

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, power-management, battery

```
router@router:~$ lsb_release -a && uname -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Linux router 4.2.0-23-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Sun Dec 27 17:47:31 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MY DUAL BOOT WINDOWS 7 GIVES ME 4:30 MIN OF BATTERY LIFE [MAX 5HR]

my setup :

1. get http://ubuntu.ntc.net.np/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso
2. get xfce4 AND My usual stuffs [ BATTERY LIFE : 3:40 HRS]
3. Installed proprietary driver for processor microcode firmware for intel CPU]
4. battery life : 4:10 HRS
5. got laptop-mode-tools setup [ BATTERY LIFE : 4:30 HRS]
6. got powertop tunning setup [ BATTERY LIFE: 5:10 HRS ]
7. got pm-utils [ps-powersave true] running [BATTERY LIFE 9:00 HRS]
8. Now how can i get more??

[image: screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT!

Answer (score 0):

You could change the mount option on your mounts within your /etc/fstab file to include noatime, which stops the timestamps changing on your files when being accessed and thus less disk action. A small change but will help somewhat.