# How heavy is unity dash?

Tags: unity, 16.04

I live in a country where there is loadshedding for 12 hours. So i heavily depend on an external inverter. When I am using some resource heavy applications or playing video my inverter makes a certain sound which indicates more power is being consumed.

Guess what same thing happen when i open unity dash.

Press super key > dash ON  > inverter sound ON

press super key again > dash OFF > inverter sound OFF

what is running as soon as i open dash that consumes more power. Because if i use the same with synapse or albert search no such activity occurs

P.S the inverter sound is although mild , it gets somehow noticiable while  more power is consumed.

PPS . I do have a dual boot partition which i have named "ubuntu-battery" - running xfce4, with only required kernels for my laptop. Although I have to thank ubuntu 16.04. even with unity its giving me quite an amazing battery life.

Comment: It does appear that from your own experience, using Unity Dash consumes more power than Xfce. What is your question? How can we help?

Comment: See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower and http://www.planetwatt.com/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/719356/can-i-get-more-battery-life-than-this

Comment: Run powerstat, that will give you some idea of the power being used. If you have a modern Intel CPU you can use the RAPL interface to get some very accurate power readings; use powerstat - Ra 1

Comment: So I just did a measurement on my Lenovo X220 and it's about 1.2W for the dash to be enabled

Comment: yes its confirmed. powerstat shows 2x to 3x  rise of the power consumption with unity dash. But a 720p video playback with vlc gives only 1.5x rise of power consumption.